# Parameters to a class constructor function

Tags: php, sql, json, class, loops

I'm trying to adapt a class of mine that handles tags for events stored in a JSON file. You can create tags, delete them, restore them, view them, etc. In the code below for this library you can see that I retrieve the array from the file during the constructor function so I use it and manipulate it throughout my classes' functions.

```
class tagHandler {
private $tagsFile = "/home/thomassm/public_html/functions/php/tags.json";
private $LstTags;
private $LstReturn;

function __construct() {
    $this->LstTags = array();
    if(!file_exists ($this->tagsFile)){
        $fHND = fopen($this->tagsFile, "w");
        $tmpArray = array(array("EID","EName","EColor", "EDel"));
        fwrite($fHND, json_encode($tmpArray));
        fclose($fHND);
    }

    $encodedInput = file ($this->tagsFile);
    $this->LstTags = json_decode($encodedInput[0], true);
    if(!$this->LstTags) $this->LstTags = array();
}

function __destruct(){
    $this->update();
}
public function update(){
    $this->LstTags = array_values($this->LstTags);

    $fHND = fopen($this->tagsFile, "w");
    fwrite($fHND, json_encode($this->LstTags));
    fclose($fHND);

    //empty memory region
    $this->LstTags = array();
    $encodedInput = file ($this->tagsFile);
    $this->LstTags = json_decode($encodedInput[0], true);
}
//More functions that use the collected array here.
```

I am trying to adapt the class to deal with people signed up to my events. Each event has a record in my database that will store a field for an array of males who sign up and females who sign up. I wish for the constructor class to get the arrays(s) from the record so they can be manipulated like the previous class. The issue is to get the array I have to search the DB for a record with the Event ID (EID) and that will require a variable passed to the constructor function. To make things worse, this parameter has to be able to change in a loop. For example, the page listing all the events will have to use this class in a loop going through each record, so it can retrieve the array to manipulate it and then show it in a table / fullcalendar before repeating the process to get the next event. I have put the code I have so far below. Its not complete (some variables haven't been renamed to male and female, etc) and may be completely wrong, but it will give you a base to explain from.

```
class signupHandler {
private $LstMaleS;
private $LstFemaleS;
private $LstReturn;

function __construct($IntEID) {
    $this->LstTags = array();

    $StrQuery = "SELECT MaleS, FemaleS FROM tblEvents WHERE EID = ?";

    if ($statement = TF_Core::$MySQLi->DB->prepare($StrQuery)) {
        $statement->bind_param('s',$IntEID);
        $statement->execute ();
        $results = $statement->get_result ();
    }

    $this->LstTags = json_decode($encodedInput[0], true);
    if(!$this->LstTags) $this->LstTags = array();
}
```

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: What I would do is pass the database result array in the constructor of `signupHandler` instead. You can query for this outside the class and initialise the class. This way you could also use the class to hold a new entry that's not yet in the database and then have a method to save that entry. This is what MVC frameworks usually do, so you could benefit from using one.

Comment: If I did that would I need constructor / destruct class at all? Or I could use a destruct to return the changed string I guess. It does sound like a pain without the class and I may as well not use the class overall if I do that as I don't think the code will that repeat much anyway.

Comment: This question is turning into a "to OOP or to not OOP" . It really is up to you. I'm just saying what is usually done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function decodeNames($StrNames){
    $this->LstNames = array();
    $this->LstNames = json_decode($StrNames, true);
    if(!$this->LstNames) $this->LstNames = array();
    $this->LstNames = array_values($this->LstNames);
}

function update(){
    $this->LstNames = array_values($this->LstNames);
    return json_encode($this->LstNames);
}

public function addSignUp($StrNames, $StrUsername, $StrStatus){
    $this->decodeNames($StrNames);

    $BlnPresent = false;

    for($i = 0; $i < count($this->LstNames); $i++){
        if($this->LstNames[$i][0] == $StrUsername){
            $this->LstNames[$i][1] = $StrStatus;
            $BlnPresent = true;
        }
    }
    if($BlnPresent == false){
        array_push($this->LstNames, array($StrUsername, $StrStatus, date("Y-m-d H:i:s")));
    }
    return $this->update();
}
```

I have decided to pass the encoded JSON array to the class each time I call a function from it. Before every function it is decoded and turned into an array and at the end it is then re-encoded and returned back to the file calling it. Now I no longer have any constructor or destruct functions.